# How to represent factorial as a product notation?

Tags: factorial, products

> **Original question:**
>   Is there any way to write $x!$ as a Pi notation?
>   $$x!=\prod\text{?}$$

The answer should have been obvious
$$x!=\prod_{r=1}^xr$$

Now I have an additional question:

> Is it possible to write $\left(2(\ x+1 )\ \right)!$ as a product notation?
>   $$(2(x+1))!=\prod?$$

Comment: Hmmm... this is the first line in the [Wikipedia article's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) section on "Definition."

Comment: @user296602 yes silly me. I have an additional question

Comment: Please do not substantially edit your question after it's already received several answers - it wastes the time of the people who already answered. Ask a new question.

Comment: Also, for the new question, it's **exactly** the same as the first after replacing $x$ by $2x + 1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write like this:
$$x!=\prod_{r=1}^x\text{r}$$

For additional question:

$$(2x+2)!=\prod_{r=1}^{(2x+2)}\text{r}$$

Comment: I shouldve seen it coming. Thanks

Comment: I now have an additional question

Comment: @JohnGlenn i have added answer for additional question

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. We have definition of n! as product (r), running from 1 to n.
I hope you asked for this pardon otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

For a non-integer  number,

$n!=\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\left( \frac{k+1}{k}\right)^{n}\frac{k}{n+k}.$